# Change the location of on screen buttons bar

Tags: user-interface

The on screen buttons bar "Back, Home, menu" are not convinently located at the bottom of the tablet screen as it is in close proximity of controls of the program being run.  Specifically I am using a SNES emulator and it's using that area for it's joypad control.

It would be very helpful if I can move the bar to the top of the screen, is there any program to do this?

Comment: What device? What version of Android?

Comment: I have a tablet Acer Iconia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy), one of the Android Engineers, stated in a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930213/390989): No, you cannot move the Honeycomb status bar, either via a setting or programmatically (meaning it's not possible for an app to move it for you). You'd have to modify and build the Honeycomb source if you wanted to have any chance of accomplishing this.

You could, however, try to find an emulator that lets you move the controls to the top of the screen. I recall seeing one that had this option, but I don't remember which one (I think it may have been Snes9x, but I'm not positive).

Comment: So it's basically no go, ok.

Answer (score 0):

One of the apps, elderathis might be referring to is [Button Savior](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.smart.swkey&hl=en). One does need to be rooted to make use of it, though.

Comment: I was actually referring to SNES emulators that let you adjust the location of the gamepad controls. Button savior won't really do anything here - you'll just end up with two sets of soft buttons on Honeycomb.

Comment: I have a tablet Acer Iconia